# when is that a comment is better than an answer?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

This is my first post on meta, so I hope to say something that makes sense.

I often see comments that if they had been posted as answers they could be acceptable ones. The problem I see in this is that other users are refrained from posting answers that would add little to the comment, leaving the question virtually unaswered when actually it is not.

My question is, why does this happen? I am the only one who believes that this is a problem?

Comment: I think a lot of people agree it can be an issue; there's been extensive discussion about this already [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148/264), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1559/264), and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3216/264).

Comment: Why the deuce do I have the crazy impression that you are a fan of Leonardo Pisano Bigollo? (Sometimes called Fibonacci).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can only answer for myself.

Usually I write a comment in lieu of an answer if I believe that any vaguely competent mathematician could answer the question at least as well as I   and that it would be fussy to transform the comment into an official answer.

It may happen however that I give an answer to a very easy or standard question if I feel that this answer has some twist that I (subjectively) find unexpected or elegant: here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91548/3217) and here is [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63991/3217).

Comment: Is this why you decided to comment on the question, and only later wrote an answer? :-)

Comment: "vaguely competent mathematician" --- I think I'll put that on my business cards.

Comment: Dear @Gerry, although the qualification is totally absurd when applied to a mathematician of your caliber, I admit that your comment made me laugh.

Comment: By this behaviour you leave a potentially valid answer that everyone may consider solving the question and thus leaving the question dwell forever in the [unanswered questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list. Basically you break one useful tool to find interesting questions to answer. If you feel too humble to obtain rep for such a - by your standards - simple answer, just turn it community wiki instead. That way you also permit others to expand on it if deemed necessary while you don't have to bother with the trivial details ;)

Comment: > I can only answer for myself. That's a refreshing attitude. Thank you. The opposite end of the spectrum is the people who pontificate as if they speak for the entire mathematical community.